# Why can't I find jquery code in Visual studio?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code

I am the freshman for `vscode`, in my home the code is work, but in the other place, the code doesn't work,  I cannot resolve it?

When I click the jquery link in the script, it shows in vs code, and it exits, but in the browser, it shows:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> test.html:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Make sure you're importing the right path of your jquery.

Comment: it is right path,when i click the path, it can open,and show the content

Comment: you are right ,i find the question,Request URL:file:///D:/javascript/jquery-1.6.3.js. but my real path is D:/2017web/javascript/jquery-1.6.3.js

Answer (score 0):

it is a fool question, the reason is path, I reslove it add the prefix **./** . thanks everyone.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaJo9.png